# Rendering issue with checkboxes nested within a 3rd-party component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

(First off: this is company code, so any samples will be contrived and probably not as complete as they otherwise could be. Also, this involves an old version of Bootstrap for React, and a 3rd-party component that is not currently actively maintained. So, I don't have illusions about my odds here.)

I have a case where I'm creating a set of checkboxes via Bootstrap. They are created within a per-row callback for a table that is itself created by [react-calendar-timeline](https://github.com/namespace-ee/react-calendar-timeline). Each checkbox is a managed element and the callback I've assigned to onChange is correctly updating application state (via a reducer dispatcher). The problem is, the checkbox doesn't re-render when clicked. From my best analysis, the Timeline component (from r-c-t) takes `groupRenderer` as a prop, which is the callback that creates the checkboxes, but the callback itself doesn't change. Thus, Timeline never re-renders and never triggers its children to re-render. I've tried creating the callback itself both with and without `useCallback`, but no change to the behavior. No amount of clicking the boxes convinces the r-c-t calendar to re-render. It looks a little like:

```js
const Calendar = (props) => {
  ...
  <Timeline
    groups={groupsList}
    groupRenderer={groupRenderer}
    ...
  />
  ...
};
```

`groupRenderer` is (probably) the problem here. Since it doesn't change, there's no reason for `Timeline` to re-render. And the checkboxes are nested within the markup for `Timeline`.

The component that uses r-c-t is one of two children of a top-level component. The logic I am trying to pull off here is that the state of the checkboxes in this component (`Calendar`) is available to the other (sibling) component (`Scheduler`). The problem isn't in tracking the state of the checkboxes; the state/dispatcher pair that I've set up via `useReducer` is working fine. It's just the visual state of the boxes themselves that I am having issue with.